# Ruby - Shorthand for fetch and return empty hash if no match?

Tags: ruby

Lets say I have

```
hsh = {}
hsh.fetch(:foobar){{}}
=> {}
```

Is there a shorthand for `hsh.fetch(:somekey){{}}`?

Would be useful when I start chaining things, i.e.

`get_product.fetch(:description){{}}.fetch(:summary){{}}`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to documentation

```
hsh.fetch(:foobar,{})
```

Comment: that looks nicer. will try that.

Answer (score 4):

crackedmind's answer is the correct answer to your question. But your example look looks like your are looking for a convenient way to dig into a nested hash.

If you are already on Ruby `>= 2.3` you might want to use `dig` instead. From the [documentation of `Hash#dig`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Hash.html#method-i-dig) (note that `dig` is also defined on `Array`, `OpenStruct` and `Struct`):

> Extracts the nested value specified by the sequence of idx objects by calling dig at each step, returning nil if any intermediate step is nil.
>
> ```
> h = { foo: {bar: {baz: 1}}}
>
> h.dig(:foo, :bar, :baz)           #=> 1
> h.dig(:foo, :zot, :xyz)           #=> nil
>
> g = { foo: [10, 11, 12] }
> g.dig(:foo, 1)                    #=> 11
> ```

You can re-write your example

```
get_product.fetch(:description){{}}.fetch(:summary){{}}
```

with `dig` like this:

```
get_product.dig(:description, :summary) || {}
```

Comment: wow. that's great. wish I was on Ruby 2.3. Still using 1.9.3 for most projects. You are absolutely right. I am looking for a convenient way to dig into a nested hash.

Comment: David, you could of course create your own `Hash#dig` if you'd have frequent use for it. I was going to also suggest you could put it in a `Refinement`, that you would `include`, but then remembered `Refinements` are post-v1.9 as well.

Comment: I heard about the ruby_dig gem as well. May end up using that instead.